# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: laravel

The `.env` file is set up correctly, using `tinker` and retrieving records works but when I try to run a route that uses a controller that uses the same call as I did in tinker the document resolves with an error that I am not using a password.

I have set up the database profile to be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` I believe this is causing the strange behavior. But this is the recommended DB type.

Comment: Do you cache the config before.

Comment: no I tried config:clear as well but error remains

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Did you try running `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: Can u post your config/database.php?

Comment: @Mark it happen sometime if you have any issue with migration

Comment: @Mark Also check that do you have user "root" in mysql and also check for permissions of "root" user.

Comment: Did you restart `php artisan serve` command after edit the `.env` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
php artisan config:cache

And 
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: this is not an answer, it's just a comment, which was actually done 43 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that password or login to the Database are incorrect. You can change these settings in .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Then removed that file

```
/bootstap/cache/config.php
```

May be the issue is that old config file was cached.

Comment: he have clear the config cache. this is not the answer.

Comment: Do you use docker? Another problem may be in your password for example DB_PASSWORD="qoq#12ba" but all the value with # as this is the "feature"of 5.8 it treat # as comment delimeter

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-root-at-localhost-using-password-yes